# postgres update table with time evolution column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Having this table at hand:

```
SELECT * FROM mutable LIMIT 10;
user_id |     session_id     |       timestamp        
---------+--------------------+------------------------
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:09:04+01
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:09:07+01
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:35+01
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:37+01
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:39+01
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:41+01
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:43+01
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:45+01
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:47+01
     180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:49+01
(10 rows)
```

So I want to modify the table by adding a column `t_evolution` that shows keeping track of the duration from one record occurrence to the next, considering the `timestamp` columns, like so:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|     user_id |     session_id     |       timestamp      |    t_evolution     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:09:04+01  |        0           |
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:09:07+01  |        3           |
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:35+01  |       92           |
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:37+01  |       94           |
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:39+01  |       96           |
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:41+01  |       98           |
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:43+01  |      100           |
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:45+01  |      102           |
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:47+01  |      104           |
|      180 | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20 12:10:49+01  |      106           |
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
(10 rows)
```

Comment: In the 3d row of your expected results t_evolution should be 91 and all the rest minus 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract the 1st timestamp from each of the timestamps and use `EXTRACT()` to get the number of seconds.
With window function `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT *,
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ("timestamp" - FIRST_VALUE("timestamp") OVER (ORDER BY "timestamp"))) t_evolution
FROM mutable
```

In your sample data all rows contain the same value for the columns `user_id` and `session_id`. If you want the new column to keeping track of the duration for each `user_id` and/or `session_id` then you may change the `OVER` clause to:

```
OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY "timestamp")
```

or:

```
OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, session_id ORDER BY "timestamp")
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aiUS4YfJtbe5oVyXgChZ2Y/0).
Results:

```
| user_id | session_id         | timestamp                | t_evolution |
| ------- | ------------------ | ------------------------ | ----------- |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:09:04.000Z | 0           |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:09:07.000Z | 3           |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:10:35.000Z | 91          |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:10:37.000Z | 93          |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:10:39.000Z | 95          |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:10:41.000Z | 97          |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:10:43.000Z | 99          |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:10:45.000Z | 101         |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:10:47.000Z | 103         |
| 180     | 179020080820120904 | 2008-08-20T12:10:49.000Z | 105         |
```

Comment: So I can do `update table add column t_evolution using #your_query`..?

Comment: Do you want to create a new column in the table?

Comment: @yes, making use of  `OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, session_id ORDER BY "timestamp") ` as you observed.

Comment: What is your version of Postgresql?

Comment: `PostgreSQL 9.6.17 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.6.17-2.pgdg18.04+1)`

Comment: Give me a few mins.

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h3AjQW6ddXQteieX47do4o/0

Comment: Thank you, you make my day.